# Insert Query Issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting issue while inserting a row into a database. Before adding new column my data inserted properly into the database.

But after adding a new column, I get an error

> Error #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

though my column names are correct as well column count and value count are same. Following is my query. Thanks in advance.

```
insert into `pb_customer_request`
    (`request_type`, `user_id`, 
     `complain_date`, `initial_price`, 
     `confirmed`, `priority`, 
     `assign_date`, `complain_type_id`, 
     `complain_status_id`, `created_by`, 
     `updated_by`, `email_send`) 
values 
    (Repairs, 13422, 
     2017-12-20 16:58:36, 0, 
     0, 1, 
     2017-12-20 16:58:36, 1, 
     1, 13420, 
     13420, 0)
```

Comment: I re-indented your code, so it's easier to count and match columns vs. values. I don't know laravel, is `Repairs` without any quotation marks ok? and the timestamps without quotation marks?

Comment: I have tried with quotation also but getting same error.

Comment: This doesn't look like laravel, it just looks like a mysql insert statement. And it probably isn't going to work without some double quotes around your string and date literals.

Comment: Please share the table definition.

Comment: @JNevill I tried with quotes but it's not working.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai  email_send enum('1', '0')

Comment: @Nikita, I mean to say the whole create table statement or the whole table structure?

Comment: At this point, there isn't much we can do to help. With the exceptions of the very necessary quotes around your string literal and date literals, your insert statement is written correctly. Clearly something else is the issue, but there isn't anything else for us to go off of at this point.

Comment: What's the Laravel / PHP code you're using to insert this data?